# Convert new Promise to Async/await in modal method

Tags: javascript, promise

I have tried to convert these pieces of code to async/await. But seem it is impossible!!! Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in that code that's async/awaitable _except_ for the promise.

Comment: The only asynchronous piece of code here is the `subscribe()` callback. Given event subscriptions don't typically return a promise because they fire more than once, it's unlikely there's anything else you can do with this code

Comment: TL;DR you cannot _promisify_ a callback based API without `new Promise()`

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in comment, you can't await events that don't supply a promise interface without creating a new promise. You could, however, promisify firing of the event and process `popupData.data` outside of the promise executor function. The `await` operator will still need to be used in an [async function or JavaScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Example in vanilla JS:

```
async methodName() {
  if (this.notificationPopupSubscription) this.notificationPopupSubscription.unsubscribe();

  const popup = await new Promise(resolve => {
    this.notificationPopupSubscription = modal.onAnyCloseEventFinished.subscribe(resolve);
  });
  const popupData = popup.getData();
  popup.removeData();
  if (!popupData.data) {
    throw Error("no data"); // reject promise returned by async method
  }
  return popupData.data;  // fulfill promise ...
}
```

In the example, `this.notificationPopupSubscription` is set synchronously in the executor, but the popup variable is set after waiting for the promise to be resolved. The enclosing function/class method still needs to be called with an appropriate `this` value of course.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was doubted and now I can be sure it's impossible to convert it to no new Promise().